# Lodash _.reduce() "Expected 2-3 arguments, but got 2" error in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, lodash

I am trying to reduce `ListAdItemResponse[]` collection to `{[name: string]: Date}` type in one of my tests and check that each subsequent published date comes before the current one (e.g. sorted by `publishedAt` in descending order):

```
 _.reduce<ListAdItemResponse, {[name: string]: Date}>(
   data,
   (result, val) => {
     expect(new Date(val.publishedAt)).to.be.beforeTime(
       new Date(result.publishedAt),
      )
     return {publishedAt: val.publishedAt}
   })
```

Using TypeScript 2.9.2, I am getting this strange contradictory error ("Expected 2-3 arguments, but got 2"). According to Lodash docs, the third argument is optional, but I can't get past this error no matter what I try. Any idea what may be wrong here? Thanks.

P.S. This compiles without error, but breaks my test, obviously:

```
_.reduce<ListAdItemResponse, {[name: string]: Date}>(
  data,
  (result, val) => {
    expect(new Date(val.publishedAt)).to.be.beforeTime(
      new Date(result.publishedAt),
    )
    return {publishedAt: val.publishedAt}
  }, {}) // with {} added as 3rd argument
```

**Update 9/2/18:**

Per @Matt's suggestion, I've tried this approach, but got 3 compilation errors this time. Looks like it's expecting `alis.data` collection type to be `{[name: string]: Date}` instead of `ListAdItemResponse[]` as it is now:

```
_.reduce<{[name: string]: Date}>(
  alis.data, // <-- error 1: Argument of type 'ListAdItemResponse[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ [name: string]: Date; } | null | undefined'.Type 'ListAdItemResponse[]' is not assignable to type '{ [name: string]: Date; }'. Index signature is missing in type 'ListAdItemResponse[]'.
  (result, val) => { // <-- errors 2,3: Parameter 'result' implicitly has an 'any' type. Parameter 'val' implicitly has an 'any' type.
    expect(new Date(val.publishedAt)).to.be.beforeTime(
      new Date(result.publishedAt),
    )
    return {publishedAt: val.publishedAt}
  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to omit the third argument, then the type of the input items and the accumulator should be the same, so you are expected to pass only a single type argument:

```
_.reduce<{[name: string]: Date}>(...)
```

I filed [an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26835) for the contradictory error message.

### Round 2

Even though the number of errors has increased, you are closer to the goal!  Assuming the definition of `ListAdItemResponse` looks something like this:

```
interface ListAdItemResponse {
    publishedAt: Date;
    // other fields...
}
```

then your call to `_.reduce` does not match the overload you intend because `ListAdItemResponse` is not assignable to `{[name: string]: Date}` because it doesn't have an index signature.  (Confusingly, TypeScript's error #1 is based on the incorrect assumption that you want a different overload that is meant for reducing over keys of an object.)  There's a special exception for object literal types like the one you are returning from the reducer.  What you should probably do is change the state type to `{publishedAt: Date}` because that's the only field you're using:

```
_.reduce<{publishedAt: Date}>(...)
```

This should make errors #2 and #3 go away too.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried this approach too (I think I've tried all of them by now), but it gave me 3 compilation errors with error #1 being the biggest problem as I can fix #2,3 by typing `result` and `val` arguments. I've updated the description to show what I've got.

Comment: You are the man! This, indeed, made those errors go away. I am still trying to wrap my head around this solution, but thank you so much for guiding me in the right way. Being able to find the right type for `_.reduce()` and `_.map()` type of methods is always a challenge for me.